# Phpmyadmin error: 'Undefined index: utf8'

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, undefined

I installed phpMyAdmin, but I have an error on the main page:

```
Notice in ./index.php#312
  Undefined index: utf8
```

Index p.312:

```
    echo '           ' , $mysql_charsets_descriptions[$mysql_charset_map['utf-8']];
```

Any idea how I can fix it?
Thank you !

Comment: I'm guessing that this is probably the result of a missing requirement, like a certain version of MySQL, or not having the MySQL PHP module installed.

Comment: I'm using MySQL 10.6.5 & the module is also installed. This error did not appear before I reinstalled the prerequisites, is it possible to change that or do I have to completely reinstall mysql? If I reinstall mysql will phpmyadmin also have to be reinstalled?

Comment: There is no MySQL 10.6.5, do you mean MariaDB? (Not sure if that's your issue, but perhaps something to check.)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mean MariaDB

Answer (score 1):

in index.php change

`echo '           ' , $mysql_charsets_descriptions[$mysql_charset_map['utf-8']];`

to

`echo '           ' , $mysql_charsets_descriptions['utf8mb4'];`

this is not required other than the error popup being annoying.
it sets some html in the page source.

`<span lang="en" dir="ltr">           UTF-8 Unicode           (utf8)        </span>`

Alternatively you can edit the array directly in /libraries/common.inc.php line 1121

`'utf-8' => 'utf8',`  to  `'utf-8' => 'utf8mb4',`

Comment: You are a lifesaver. On my system though (centOS) it is located here: libraries\select_lang.lib.php

Answer (score 1):

maybe it will help someone... I had same issue, but not exactly the same solution.

In my case **phpmyadmin ver. 4.8.3** running with **MySQL 8.0.30**.

Solution was not in the common.inc.php. In my case I had to edit /libraries/classes/Charsets.php line 43:
`'utf-8'        => 'utf8',` to `'utf-8'        => 'utf8mb3',`

Cheers